# Ansible unarchive module failure: "Failed to validate the SSL certificate"

Tags: ubuntu, python, ansible

Recently I have been changing the way that the Python environment on client machines, configured using Ansible, are setup.

This has involved minimising the number of packages installed and configured in the system Python install (on Ubuntu 14.04 clients), to avoid the potential for library conflicts when the client machines are subsequently used for development activities.

Since having made this change I have been having issues with the [`unarchive` Ansible module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/unarchive_module.html) failing to validate SSL certificates if the `remote_src` is used in conjunction with an HTTPS URL.

An example of a command which has been failing is as follows:

```
- name: Get and untar opus-1.1.2
  unarchive:
    src="http://downloads.xiph.org/releases/opus/opus-1.1.2.tar.gz"
    dest="/opt/library-sources"
    remote_src=yes
```

When run, the above command fails with the following error message:

```
fatal: [10.0.0.90]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Failed to validate the SSL certificate for downloads.xiph.org:443. Make sure your managed systems have a valid CA certificate installed. If the website serving the url uses SNI you need python >= 2.7.9 on your managed machine or you can install the `urllib3`, `pyopenssl`, `ndg-httpsclient`, and `pyasn1` python modules to perform SNI verification in python >= 2.6. You can use validate_certs=False if you do not need to confirm the servers identity but this is unsafe and not recommended. Paths checked for this platform: /etc/ssl/certs, /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem, /etc/pki/tls/certs, /usr/share/ca-certificates/cacert.org, /etc/ansible"}
```

My understanding of this error is that Python libraries are missing which the `unarchive` is dependent on.

What I haven't been able to figure out from any of the Ansible documentation is whether these packages are requirements of the Python environment on the server machine (charged with running the Ansible scripts) and or the client machines (on which the tasks detailed in the Ansible scripts are executed).

It should be noted that I have Ansible installed on the server machine (also running Ubuntu 14.04), via `pip` which also has the following versions of the packages mentioned in the error message installed:

```
urllib3==1.7.1
ndg-httpsclient==0.4.3
pyasn1==0.4.2
pyOpenSSL==0.13
```

This leads me to believe that these packages are likely required on client machine as well as the server.

Does anybody know on which machines (server and or client) these packages are required? I would also be interested to know where this is documented because it may raise issues elsewhere in my Ansible scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be aware that [`unarchive`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/unarchive_module.html) takes place on the server which ansible is managing, not the machine on which you are running it, when `remote_src=yes` and the `src` is a URL.

You should further be aware that visiting http://downloads.xiph.org/ redirects to https://downloads.xiph.org/ which is a secure web site, which further redirects to https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/xiph/ if you manage to get that far.

As such, the SSL certificate validation takes place on that server, and the software and CA certificates necessary to perform that validation must be on that server. Further, they need to be system packages, not packages you have installed yourself with `pip`. You should ensure that installing these prerequisites is among the earliest provisioning tasks you run.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHampton. Do you know if this is detailed anywhere in the Ansible documentation, source code or similar?

Comment: Huh? What is it you want further documentation of?

Comment: Having done a bit more reading I understand that all modules run remotely unless they bring action plugins with them. (For more details can be found here: [Do Ansible modules run locally or on the remote host?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37079451/7647013)) Therefor, as you state the `unarchive` module executes on the machine that is being managed via Ansible. For clarity it should be noted this is the case with or without the `remote_src` option. The `remote_src` option only controls the source location of the archive. However, URLs can only be used as the `src` if `remote_src=yes`.